# Fuente via JavaScript en video source tag html5

Tags: javascript, html, html-video

Tengo el siguiente código en html:

```
<video width=100% height=1000 src="http://video.wmspanel.com/local/raw/ndi-setup.mp4/playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" controls autoplay></video>
```

No es más que la etiqueta video con un source en .m3u8

```
src="http://video.wmspanel.com/local/raw/ndi-setup.mp4/playlist.m3u8"
```

Pero quiero hacer lo siguiente:

Mediante una variable en javascript:

```
var fuente = "http://video.wmspanel.com/local/raw/ndi-setup.mp4/playlist.m3u8";
```

determinar la fuente "src" de la etiqueta video.

```
<video width=100% height=1000 src="fuente" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" controls autoplay></video>
```

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo hacerlo?

Intenté hacerlo justamente así:

```
<script>var fuente = "http://video.wmspanel.com/local/raw/ndi-setup.mp4/playlist.m3u8";</script>

<video width=100% height=1000 src="fuente" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" controls autoplay></video>
```

Pero no ha funcionado.
Funciona sin problema con otros reproductores como "Clappr" o "JW Player", sin embargo con la etiqueta "video" de html5 no va.

Gracias por responder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lo que intentas es algo así, para asignarle el nuevo valor al atributo has de especificarlo.

```
<video controls>
  <source src="" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
<script>
 document.querySelector("video").src = "https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/mov_bbb.mp4";
 document.querySelector("video").load();
</script>
```

Puedes ver mas aquí

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_src.asp

Comment: Eso es justamente lo que buscaba.